# Trigger to extract parts from JSON blob in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, triggers

I have an application that passes around a lot of JSON. There is some analytical work that would be best handled by PG, so I thought I'd pass the records to PG, let a trigger extract into another table, and allow users to run analysis on that other table. I cannot however seem to get the function to handle the JSON data correctly.

Sample table:

```
create table if not exists json_testing.test_table
(
    json_col jsonb
);
```

Sample trigger:

```
create or replace trigger split_record
    after insert
    on json_testing.test_table
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE record_splitter();
```

Sample JSON:

```
{
    "attr1": 1,
    "attr2": 2
}
```

And the function which I just can't seem to get working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION record_splitter()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO json_testing.some_other_table(col1, col2)
    SELECT NEW->'attr_1', NEW->'attr_2';
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
```

```
[2023-03-05 18:17:15] [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: json_testing.test_table -> unknown
[2023-03-05 18:17:15] Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
[2023-03-05 18:17:15] Where: PL/pgSQL function record_splitter() line 3 at SQL statement
```

I feel like I'm doing something silly here. It seems to be trying to coerce the table itself into some other datatype, as opposed to treating NEW as a json blob...

Comment: `NEW.json_col` as `NEW` by itself is the complete new ROW. Postgres does not know that the `ROW` is only one field, you have to be specific about what you want. FYI, every table has an associated composite type that is equal to all the fields in the table. That is where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Adrian Klaver said in his comment, you need to include the column name. Additionally, you can use a `VALUES` clause for better performance:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION record_splitter()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO json_testing.some_other_table(col1, col2)
    VALUES (NEW.json_col->'attr_1', NEW.json_col->'attr_2');
    RETURN NEW;
END; $$
```

Comment: Hurrah. Adding in a cast to ints for the two colums made this work for me